# Dalvik Error 1 When exporting Signed Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse

This error only happens when I try to export a signed application or unsigned application using the Android tools in eclipse.

I'm not entirely sure if this has any impact, but during the time I've been working on this, I have been able to test my builds on my device and the emulator. So I'm not sure if it would be an error with my code.

I'm currently using Twitter4j, the Facebook SDK, and the ZXing scanner library in this project if that has any impact too.

I've tried cleaning the project, I've made sure that any libraries I'm using are in the libs folder of the project, and much more.

Comment: Have you tried exporting without proguard? Or do you have any proguard directives artifacts?

Comment: Had the error once, cleaned, rebuild and it worked. You properly have some kind of error in the code.